# How to insert into RAILS db via external RESTful call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, curl

SOLVED: I had done a few things wrong, all of which involved my controller RECEIVING the data. There was not anything wrong with the methods below on SENDING the data.

1: I was not using @report.save in my reportController#create

2: I was not passing params[:report] in my controller

3: I added "skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token" to my applicaiton controller to stop warnings in the logs.
Solved. data insertion successful.

=====ORIG. Question Below=====

I need an external program to issue a command that inserts stuff into a Ruby on Rails database. 
I understand the security implications of this, but because this application is not public facing, it is not really an issue.

This is the workflow i am looking to achieve:

REST client > RAILS > create new DB TABLE row

For purposes of example: my route.rb file contains

```
resources :reports
```

so i am able to CRUD using those routes. I just cant seem to get my rest client to work correctly.

UPDATE:
I have tried a RUBY rest client AND curl command in ONE, to no avail.

```
require 'rest_client'
require 'json'

hash_to_send = {:test_name => 'Fake Name', :pass_fail => 'pass',:run_id => 1111, :category => 'Fake Category'}

#formulate CURL attempt
myCommand =  "curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST   http://localhost:8889/report.json -d #{hash_to_send.to_json} > deleteme.html"
#execute CURL attempt
`#{myCommand}` # RESULT--> 795: unexpected token at 'test_name:Fake Name'


#Make Ruby rest client attempt
response = RestClient.post( "http://localhost:8889/report.json", 
  hash_to_send.to_json, 
  :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
)

#debug info 
puts myCommand # Returns --> {"test_name":"Fake Name","pass_fail":"pass","run_id":1111,"category":"Fake Category"}
```

Comment: SOLVED: I had done a few things wrong.
1: Was not using @report.save in my reportController#create

Answer (score 1):

Instead of curl in command-line, use ruby script and handle REST calls and JSON conversion by gems. For example, using `rest-client` gem (https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) and standard `json` gem you can write:

```
require 'rest_client'
require 'json'

response = RestClient.post( "http://localhost:8889/report.json", 
  params_in_hash.to_json, 
  { :content_type => :json, :accept => :json }
)
```

Comment: I am aware of this, and have attempted to no avail. however the error is not as descriptive.  

  Here is what i wrote 
`require 'rest_client'`
 `require 'json'`

`hash_to_send = {:test_name => "Fake Name", :pass_fail => "pass"}`
`response = RestClient.post( "http://localhost:8889/report.json", 
  hash_to_send.to_json, 
  :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
)
`
`puts response.inspect`


The result was a 500 error.

Comment: Sorry i do not know how to format my code in the response. the backticks do not seem to work as described in the "help"

Comment: Oops, I misled you. Try to put HTTP headers in hash: `{ :content_type => :json, :accept => :json }` (original post already updated)

Comment: blerg. No dice.
    unexpected token at '{"report":{"test_name":"Fake'